# R: Resampling Control Group in Propensity Scoriing

Tags: r, statistics

I am currently working on a propensity scoring match model.

An example of my code is provided below:

```
library(MatchIt)

head(data)

match.it.data <- matchit(TARGET ~ PROBABILITY, data = data, method = "nearest", ratio = 1)
```

I was wondering if anyone knew how to allow my Treated group observations to be matched with the Control group observations more than once.

In other words, a control group observation would be able to be matched with my Treated group more than once. So, rather than doing a one to one doing a one to the closest possible. So, potentially allow the the treated group to resample the control group more than once sort of like a bootstrap simulation would work with multiple iterations.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `replace = TRUE` in the call to `matchit()`.